# js to add new form dynamically

Tags: javascript, laravel

i'm working on laravel 5.7 
and i need a script to add new form when clicked plus button

i found this script but its only add input fields i need to add the whole form

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div id="post"><input type="text" name="options[]" class="form-control"><input type="text" name="options[]" class="form-control"></div><br>'); //add input box
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please lool https://handlebarsjs.com or manipulating dom element

Comment: you can create the form and set the property to hidden, upon clicked then show the form.

Answer (score 0):

Don't inject dom elements via javascript, it's not good practice. As already mentioned above have a look at handlebars, where you can store your form template in an own file. Also vue.js would be a good choice, if you have more to do than just creating a form.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at a few JS methods for this...

createElement() - this creates an html DOM element. For example...

```
let myDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

Once you have created the element, it will sit out there in the aether until you actually put it on the page. This is where a method like appendChild() comes in to play...

```
document.querySelector('someElement').appendChild(myDiv);
// This will append the myDiv element you created to your someElement
```

You can also create text with createTextNode('your text') and append it the same way.
There is also a setAttribute() method that takes two parameters...the first is the attribute to set and the second is the value to set it.